# Create NSString from strings within a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSDictionary where both the keys and values are NSStrings and I'd like to create one NSString from them in the form of

```
Key1: Value1
Key2: Value2
```

What is the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets assume your dictionary is called `myDict` and `key` is the value of the key you are looking for

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", key, [myDict objectForKey: key]];
```

This will return

```
Key: Value
```

Of course if this is just for you logging on the console you can make life easier for yourself and do something like

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myDict description]);
```

Edit::

To display the entire dictionary you can use a for each loop thusly:

```
NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString string];

for(NSString *key in [myDict allKeys]){

    [finalString appendFormat:@"%@: %@\n", key, [myDict objectForKey: key]];

}
```

Comment: Just `NSLog(@"%@", myDict);` is enough, the `-description` will be called automatically.

Comment: When reading it back though at a later date I always find it easier to understand exactly whats happening when I use [myDict description] over myDict. I guess its just my personal preference!

Comment: This it not quite what I was after, I want one string that will be displayed on-screen which contains the whole of the dictionary in the Key: Value format.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that it outputs like in your quick example, all it does it iterate over all the keys in the dictionary and appends them to the back of a mutable string with a certain format